# What is the meaning of "file:///"?

Tags: path

Wath's the meaning of "file:///"?? I have just used it in ReportViewer to identify a path in an expression but I really don't know the meaning of it.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767731(v=vs.85)

Searching for "file:///" on the search engines does not give any usefull results :)

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding context and some explanation for your link. You can find information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).